# Replace all Uppercase Chars to Lowercase except urlencoded strings

Tags: php, redirect, preg-replace, preg-match

I have a very simple redirect in PHP that redirects to lowercase, I cannot do this in .htaccess because of my shared server limitations.

```
        if (preg_match('/[A-Z]+/', $url)){
        header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
        header("Location: ".strtolower($url));
        exit;       
    }
```

However there are certain cases where the .htaccess may have already redirected a url. All these cases have urlencoded chars ie. %7E.

So I need to check for any uppercase characters that aren't in the form of a urlencoded char and replace them with lowercase characters.

Worst (or perhaps best) case I don't want to attempt an already redirected header can I check to see if it's already been redirected in PHP.

Any ideas on how I could go about this please?

Answer (score 0):

What you simply could do is decode the url to remove the urlencoded chars, then you use strtolower(), and then encode it back:

```
header("Location: ". urlencode(strtolower(urldecode($url))));
```